# Subset a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of bundles and I would like to subset it based on the column sum (a budget) and the first value. If the first value is 0 and I could add the value in and still be under the budget I would like to drop the column.

For example, if my budget is 10 (column sum) and my matrix looks like this:

```
     col1     col2          col3       col4
1       2        2           0           0
2       3        3           3           3
3       0        0           2           0
4       4        0           4           0
```

I would like the end matrix to look like this because the 0 in col4 row 1 could be included and the column sum would be under 10:

```
     col1     col2          col3       
1       2        2           0           
2       3        3           3           
3       0        0           2          
4       4        0           4
```

My code is currently:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if (df[1,i]==0) {
    df<-df[,which(colSums(df)+2>10)]
    }
  }
```

The code is not working because it also removes column 2. I don't think it is considering the if statement when subsetting the matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: For col3 also first value is 0 and the sum is under 10

Comment: `df1[1,] == 0 & colSums(df1) < 10` is getting TRUE for last two columns

Comment: What is `bids` in thee loop showed

Comment: Bids is 2 in this case (the value of the first row). Sorry about that!

Comment: Please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the solution by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197870/12158757), but I think the following subset approach already can make it

```
> df[,head(df,1)!=0 | colSums(df)+2>10]
  col1 col2 col3
1    2    2    0
2    3    3    3
3    0    0    2
4    4    0    4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 4L), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 
                                                         0L), col3 = c(0L, 3L, 2L, 4L), col4 = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 0L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                     "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this. it was a bit simpler than below.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create the condition with `colSums` and the value in first row to subset the columns.  `colSums` would be more efficient

```
bids <- 2
df1[which(!(df1[1,] == 0 & (colSums(df1) + bids) < 10))]
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    2    2    0
#2    3    3    3
#3    0    0    2
#4    4    0    4
```

---

Or using the `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(df1)) if(df1[1, i] == 0 & sum(df1[[i]]) + bids < 10) df1[[i]] <- NULL
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 4L), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 
0L), col3 = c(0L, 3L, 2L, 4L), col4 = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```